# Sum subsets of vector by indices stored as vectors in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

`L` is a cell.

```
L=
 2,4,6   % j=1
 1,6,8   % j=2
 4,6     % j=3
```

`r` is a vector 1x8:

```
23 1 24 5 4 3 7 8
```

I want to vectorize this code:

```
UC=zeros(1,J);
for j=1:J
    if ~isempty(L{j})                      
        UC(j)=sum(r(L{j}));
    end
end
```

I tried this:

```
UC = arrayfun(@(x)r(x), L, 1, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

but it looks like cells are not suitable for this function.

```
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

Comment: have you looked up ``cellfun()`` yet?

Comment: @Dennis Klopfer: Yes, if I do this: UC(1:J)=cellfun(@(x)sum(r(x)), L, 'UniformOutput', false), Matlab says that conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Comment: @Dennis Klopfer: This works: UC(1:J)=cellfun(@(x)sum(r(x)), L, 'UniformOutput', true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listed in this post is an *almost* vectorized approach based upon [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). I am calling it as almost vectorized because it uses [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) which isn't really a vectorized way, but since it uses it to find the lengths of each cell only, so its effect would be minimal. Here's the implementation  -

```
lens = cellfun('length',L)
id = zeros(1,sum(lens))
id([1 cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
out = accumarray(cumsum(id(:)),r([L{:}]))
```

Comment: Will it be faster that pure cellfun solution?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos For that we need to know the datasizes and would also depend the values themselves. Benchmark at your end?

Comment: There is a colon missing, isn't it? -> `id([1; cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;` . Do you *really* thaik that would be faster? You're using cellfun anyway with much more stuff wrapped around?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Well I assumed L is a *row vector* of cells , so `lens` is a row vector and with that assumption I don't think it needs semi-colon there. Thus, OP has to add or not add semi-colon accordingly. On performance, yeah I think there is a good amount of setup involved. So, as I said it I guess it would depend on the inputs themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You just want to sum up elements of `r` according to every of your cell array elements? Then you need indeed [**`cellfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
%// given
L = { ...
 [2,4,6]   % j=1
 [1,6,8]   % j=2
 [4,6] }

r = [23 1 24 5 4 3 7 8]

%// output
out = cellfun(@(x) sum(r(x)),L)
%// or in case r is not a vector, but a matrix
out = cellfun(@(x) sum(r(x(:))),L)
```

which is the same as:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) sum(r(x{:})),L)
```

---

```
out =

     9
    34
     8
```